# Moving Template Method to Derivative Breaks Compilation

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

Given the following code:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
   T t;
};

class B
{
public:
   void foo(int i) {}

   template<typename T>
   void foo(A<T>& a) {}
};

int main()
{
   A<int> a;
   B      b;

   b.foo(a  );
   b.foo(a.t);
}
```

This compiles and works fine; the correct overloaded versions of `B::foo()` are chosen and called for `a` and `a.t`.

Now I introduce a new class `C` which derives from `B` and move the template version of `::foo()` out of `B` and into `C`:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
   T t;
};

class B
{
public:
   void foo(int i) {}
};

class C: public B
{
public:
   template<typename T>
   void foo(A<T>& a) {}
};

int main()
{
   A<int> a;
   C      c;

   c.foo(a  ); // Fine
   c.foo(a.t); // Error
}
```

And now the code won't compile anymore. Visual Studio 2005 is stating:

```
error C2784: 'void C::foo(A<T> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'A<T> &' from 'int'
```

In fact, calling `C::foo()` with any `int` value results in this error. It almost seems like the method overload for `int` is being hidden by the template overload.

Why is this happening? Is it some issue with Visual Studio 2005's compiler? Unfortunately, I cannot test it on any other compiler right now.

Any information is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It almost seems like the method overload for int is being hidden by the template overload.

Exactly! You need to add a using declaration to class C:

```
class C: public B
{
 public:
  using B::foo;
  template<typename T>
  void foo(A<T>& a) {}
};
```

When you declare a member function in a derived class, all member functions in the base class with the same name are hidden. See §3.3.10/3 of ISO/IEC 14882:2011:

> The declaration of a member in a derived class (Clause 10) hides the declaration of a member of a base class of the same name; see 10.2.

Answer (score 2):

It's hiding, no overloading. Use

```
class C: public B
{
public:
   using B::foo;
   template<typename T>
   void foo(A<T>& a) {}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct, the base function is *hidden*. That's actually the proper term for it. Add `using B::foo;` to the class definition of `C` to unhide it.